# managing certificate trust list with java source code

Tags: java, security

I am a new learner of java and I am testing Public Key Infrastructure with Java.

And i have been searching for weeks, to manipulate certificate trust list with java source code. But i can't find the solution anywhere.

Certificate Trust List (CTL) is a file extension with (.stl), which contain a list of Trusted Root Certification Authority.

If anyone know how to manage certificate trust list in java, please share me.
With Regards,

Comment: Yes it is a kind of trust store, that contain root certificates.